# How many ways are there to see all properties that you manually add to the function? JavaScript. JS

Tags: javascript, function, properties, key-value, keyvaluepair

In JavaScript functions are first-class objects, that means you can treat them just like any object, in this case, you are only adding a property to the function object.

Ok, let's add some properties to a function.

```js
  function a() {
    a.firstProp = "I'm 1st - property";
  }

  a.seccondProp = "I'm 2st - property";

  function b() {
    a();
  }

  b(); // initialize 1st property (firstProp)  for `function a`;

  console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b) );
  console.log( Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a) );
```

How can I see in Chrome DevTools a key-value pair that I added to the function in code example?

Answer (score 4):

```
  Console.log( Object.keys(a) );
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign), which copies own enumerable properties, to an empty object and have a look.

Or use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

```js
function a() {
    a.firstProp = "I'm 1st - property";
}

a.seccondProp = "I'm 2st - property";

function b() {
    a();
}

b(); // initialize 1st prop;

console.log(Object.assign({}, a));
console.log(Object.entries(a));
```

Comment: Or just use `Object.keys`.

Comment: This is the only answer that noticed the **key-value pair** phrase in the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are adding enumerable properties `firstProp` and `secondProp`. To get such properties you would usually use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) method:

```js
function a() {
  a.firstProp = "I'm 1st - property";
}

a()

a.seccondProp = "I'm 2st - property";

console.log(Object.keys(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

The other ways are shorter and superior but you might be also interested in the for in loop. For in loops over **ALL** the properties like this:

```js
function foo (){}

foo.bar = 'test';
foo.baz = 123;

for(let i in foo) {

  console.log(i);

}


console.log('------------');

for(let i of foo) {

  console.log(i);

}
```

Also note that the for in loop loops over all the properties of an object. The for of loop only loops over the object if the object is iterable (e.g. array), that's why this will produce an array.

Hope you find this helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
console.dir(a);
console.dir(b);
```

And you will have this response in the console:
[image]

Hope this helps